# Pause Discrepencies In Azure Speech Studio and Speech SDK

Tags: xml, azure, text-to-speech, ssml

I have the following ssml

```
<speak xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice name="en-US-GuyNeural"><prosody contour="(15%, +96%) (37%, -5%) (61%, -98%) (94%, +98%)">Hello Jacob</prosody><s>This is a test</s><prosody contour="(17%, +99%) (77%, -96%)">script</prosody></voice></speak>
```

When using the speech sdk, it has a break between "This is a test" and "script":

```
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
import os

# Configure the synthesizer
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
speech_config.speech_synthesis_language = "en-US" 
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

# Create ssml variable
ssml = '<speak xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US"><voice name="en-US-GuyNeural"><prosody contour="(15%, +96%) (37%, -5%) (61%, -98%) (94%, +98%)">Hello Jacob</prosody><s>This is a test</s><prosody contour="(17%, +99%) (77%, -96%)">script</prosody></voice></speak>'

# Create speech
speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_ssml_async(ssml).get()
stream = speechsdk.AudioDataStream(speech_synthesis_result)
```

I've tried uploading this same ssml to azure speech studio and it worked correctly without the pause:
[azure speech studio ssml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7Nyq.png)

How do I get rid of the pause when using the SDK?

Comment: please share the code u tried

Comment: To better assist you, could you please provide more details about what you've already tried to solve the issue? Any code snippets, error messages, or specific steps you've taken so far would be helpful. This information will help the community better understand your problem and provide more accurate solutions.

Comment: I've added more in depth code. There are no error messages, as it's not erroring, but instead producing undesirable audio.